# google maps v3 standard icon/shadow names (equiv. of G_DEFAULT_ICON in v2)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm switching icon types of google maps markers between a default one and another one (made by google chart api). To switch back to standard icon I use:

```
marker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/marker.png');
```

For another icon I use:

```
marker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/marker_yellow.png');
```

**The question is:**

1. is the URL I use really the "standard" (canonical)? Is it assured that google will not change it?
2. it would be better to use some constant like `G_DEFAULT_ICON` in gmaps api v2. Is there anything similar in api v3?
3. if not, where one can find the list of canonical icon/shadow URLs that are assured to work during all the google api v3 life?

The same question for shadows - when I set the icon, how to get the standard shadow instead of using ugly `m.setShadow(new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/shadow50.png', null, null, new google.maps.Point(10, 34)))`? (Note that `getShadow()` will not tell you anything as it returns `null` on the default icon with defaultshadow).

---

PS: there are some dynamic icons APIs but they all are now deprecated, [and no remedy has been found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11318672/684229).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`marker.setIcon(null)` will place the default icon with standard shadow...

**However, I still miss some "official" list of icons and their URLs**, or some constants like `G_DEFAULT_ICON` to accomplish this.

Answer (score 133):

I did some digging through the Google Maps - My Places creation page and there's a place to find a bunch of default icons. Not sure if they'll remain forever or not, but here's a list of almost a hundred to get you in the right direction with default icons:

**Preview PNG**

https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms2/iconm.png

[image]

---

## Row 1

**Dots**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/blue-dot.png

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/red-dot.png

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/green-dot.png

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/ltblue-dot.png

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/yellow-dot.png

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/purple-dot.png

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/pink-dot.png

Dot Shadow:
https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/msmarker.shadow.png

---

## Row 2

**Solid**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/blue.png

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/red.png

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/green.png

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/lightblue.png

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/yellow.png

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/purple.png

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/pink.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/msmarker.shadow.png

---

## Row 3

**Pushpins**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/blue-pushpin.png

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/red-pushpin.png

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/grn-pushpin.png

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/ltblu-pushpin.png

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/ylw-pushpin.png

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/purple-pushpin.png

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/pink-pushpin.png

Pushpin Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/pushpin_shadow.png

---

## Row 4

**Restaurant**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/restaurant.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/restaurant.shadow.png

**Coffeehouse**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/coffeehouse.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/coffeehouse.shadow.png

**Bar**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/bar.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/bar.shadow.png

**Snack Bar**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/snack_bar.png

Shadow:  https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/snack_bar.shadow.png

**Man**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/man.png

Shadow:

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/man.shadow.png

**Woman**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/woman.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/woman.shadow.png

**Wheel Chair Accessible**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/wheel_chair_accessible.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/wheel_chair_accessible.shadow.png

---

## Row 5

**Parking Lot**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/parkinglot.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/parkinglot.shadow.png

**Cab**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/cabs.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/cabs.shadow.png

**Bus**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/bus.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/bus.shadow.png

**Truck**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/truck.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/truck.shadow.png

**Rail**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/rail.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/rail.shadow.png

**Plane**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/plane.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/plane.shadow.png

**Ferry**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/ferry.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/ferry.shadow.png

---

## Row 6

**Helicopter**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/helicopter.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/helicopter.shadow.png

**Subway**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/subway.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/subway.shadow.png

**Tram**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/tram.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/tram.shadow.png

**Info**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/info.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/info.shadow.png

**Info Circle**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/info_circle.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/info_circle.shadow.png

**Flag**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/flag.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/flag.shadow.png

**Rainy**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/rainy.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/rainy.shadow.png

---

## Row 7

**Water**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/water.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/water.shadow.png

**Simple Snowflake**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/snowflake_simple.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/snowflake_simple.shadow.png

**Marine**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/marina.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/marina.shadow.png

**Fishing**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/fishing.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/fishing.shadow.png

**Sailing**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/sailing.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/sailing.shadow.png

**Swimming**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/swimming.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/swimming.shadow.png

**Ski**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/ski.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/ski.shadow.png

---

## Row 8

**Tree**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/tree.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/tree.shadow.png

**Campfire**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/campfire.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/campfire.shadow.png

**Picnic**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/picnic.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/picnic.shadow.png

**Campground**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/campground.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/campground.shadow.png

**Ranger Station**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/rangerstation.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/rangerstation.shadow.png

**Toilets**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/toilets.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/toilets.shadow.png

**Point of Interest (POI)**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/POI.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/POI.shadow.png

---

## Row 9

**Hiker**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/hiker.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/hiker.shadow.png

**Cycling**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/cycling.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/cycling.shadow.png

**Motorcycling**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/motorcycling.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/motorcycling.shadow.png

**Horseback Riding**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/horsebackriding.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/horsebackriding.shadow.png

**Sport Venue**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/sportvenue.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/sportvenue.shadow.png

**Golfer**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/golfer.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/golfer.shadow.png

**Trail**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/trail.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/trail.shadow.png

---

## Row 10

**Shopping**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/shopping.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/shopping.shadow.png

**Movies**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/movies.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/movies.shadow.png

**Grocery Store**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/grocerystore.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/grocerystore.shadow.png

**Convienance Store**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/convienancestore.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/convienancestore.shadow.png

**Arts**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/arts.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/arts.shadow.png

**Home Garden Business**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/homegardenbusiness.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/homegardenbusiness.shadow.png

**Electronics**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/electronics.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/electronics.shadow.png

---

## Row 11

**Mechanic**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/mechanic.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/mechanic.shadow.png

**Gas**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/gas.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/gas.shadow.png

**Real Estate**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/realestate.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/realestate.shadow.png

**Salon**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/salon.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/salon.shadow.png

**Dollar**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/dollar.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/dollar.shadow.png

**Euro**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/euro.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/euro.shadow.png

**Yen**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/yen.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/yen.shadow.png

---

## Row 12

**Fire Department**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/firedept.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/firedept.shadow.png

**Hospitals**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/hospitals.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/hospitals.shadow.png

**Lodging**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/lodging.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/lodging.shadow.png

**Phone**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/phone.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/phone.shadow.png

**Caution**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/caution.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/caution.shadow.png

**Earthquake**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/earthquake.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/earthquake.shadow.png

**Falling Rocks**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/fallingrocks.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/fallingrocks.shadow.png

---

## Row 13

**Post Office - U.S.**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/postoffice-us.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/postoffice-us.shadow.png

**Police**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/police.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/police.shadow.png

**Sunny**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/sunny.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/sunny.shadow.png

**Partly Cloudy**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/partly_cloudy.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/partly_cloudy.shadow.png

**Volcano**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/volcano.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/volcano.shadow.png

**Camera**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/camera.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/camera.shadow.png

**Webcam**

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/webcam.png

Shadow: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/webcam.shadow.png

---

Comment: Hi Douglas, thanks for answer. Where did you get those URLs from? Can you post a link please?

Comment: I don't believe there is a direct link (not that I've found at least). The quickest way to find them is view source on any Google Map - the shadow and icon are all in there. The way I built this list is: Sign in to Google, go to Maps. Click "My Places", build a custom map and put a point on it (anywhere). Click "Edit" and select the point you just made. Top right of this little edit window you can select the icon you want. In the icon selector is the preview png I have listed. After selecting an icon, view the map's source to find the related icon and shadow. 2 hours later, the list above. :)

Comment: Great answer!! Row 2 has one wrong link, it should be: https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/lightblue.png

Answer (score 4):

The best one I found was on this post :

[Google Map icons with VisualRefresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17746740/google-map-icons-with-visualrefresh)

I also found these ones on a another post [ [Google Maps Default Icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25368851/google-maps-default-icons) ]

https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?dsrcid=308519#map:id=3

Also see :

https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/2679986

Answer (score -1):

The list is [here & hosted by google](https://sites.google.com/site/gmapsdevelopment/). This lists them all(or most of them) out with the url to point to them.

Remember: They work with `HTTPS://` and `HTTP://`

> Google: [Link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers)
>
> Note: Marker shadows were removed in version 3.14 of the Maps
> JavaScript API. Any shadows specified programmatically will be
> ignored.

Using it:

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng, // this var would be set before calling this
    map: map, // this var would be set on initiating the api
    title: 'The location of the Million Dollars!',
    icon: 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png' // This is where you put the icon url
});
```

Comment: Why the negative vote?