# JavaScripts to show multi locations on map

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have written this code to show multiple locations on d map. But I want the marker to be red if the `location[i].visit_status` is 0 and green if the `location[i].visit_status` is 1 ( I have the green and red icons in my machine ) so I wrote this code but for a reason that I don't know, it is not working. can anyone help me please?

Here is the code:

```
var locations=[{"id_retailer":"3","retailer_name":"ret1","retailer_latitude":"3.083826","retailer_longitute":"101.731689","visit_date":"2011-11-11","visit_status":"0"}];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {

  zoom: 8,

  center: new google.maps.LatLng(2.67968661580376,102.23876953125),

  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

});


var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({

    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i].retailer_latitude, locations[i].retailer_longitute),

    map: map,
    if(locations[i].visit_status)
      icon: 'images/1.png';
    else
      icon: 'images/0.png';
    title: locations[i].retailer_name

  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {

    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent("Name: "+locations[i].retailer_name);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }

  })(marker, i));

}

window.onunload=GUnload;
```

Comment: RightMove project by any chance? I had an issue with google maps where it would not give the correct labels to each marker, it would only give the same one to each marker. Sometimes maps is just weird.

Comment: `GUnload`?? (at the last line) - this is API v2!

Answer (score 1):

Change this syntax

```
 map: map,
    if(locations[i].visit_status)
      icon: 'images/1.png';
    else
      icon: 'images/0.png';
```

by this other one:

```
 map: map,
 icon: locations[i].visit_status ? 'images/1.png':'images/0.png',
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend the same as Adilson, moreover, don't forget to set the icon shadow - this is example of the standard icon shadow (if you using icons that have the same shape as the standard one):

```
icon: locations[i].visit_status ? 'images/1.png' : 'images/0.png',
shadow: new google.maps.MarkerImage(
    'http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/shadow50.png',
    null,
    null,
    new google.maps.Point(10, 34)
)
```

I'd like to know some better way how to specify default shadow, but [I don't know - see this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248077/google-maps-v3-standard-icon-names-equiv-of-g-default-icon-in-v2)

Comment: thanx so much Tomas..
but I dun know why I cannot see shadow for the icon