# Google maps api v3 default icons?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Am I right in thinking that there's only ONE icon included in google maps, and to use anything other than that you have specify a URL for an image, and a URL for a shadow, etc etc?

Basically I'm shocked that all of the icons you can see if you create a "My Maps" map aren't available in the API.  It should be as simple as saying "icon: greenPin", "icon: parking", "icon: tent", surely?

Seems bizarre that they've not included such a basic thing given how powerful the rest of the API is - why make us jump through hoops giving specific URLs to images & shadows?

Am I missing something?

At the very least where can I find a list of the official *google* URLs for these "built in" images, as I'm struggling even with that.

:-S

Comment: possible duplicate of [google maps v3 standard icon/shadow names (equiv. of G\_DEFAULT\_ICON in v2)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248077/google-maps-v3-standard-icon-shadow-names-equiv-of-g-default-icon-in-v2)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes you are right, google default image is only one and if you want to another image you have to use URL.

http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png

[http://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker" + letter + ".png"](http://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker%22%20+%20letter%20+)

here you can replace the letter with any alphabet.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm surprised google don't at least make this odd limitation more obvious - I just assumed I was being blind and missing something simple!  Does seem odd that they don't have a small library of images built in to use though, doesn't it?

Comment: +1 --is odd, especially considering you can see those other "default" Google images in other uses of the maps within Google.

Answer (score 13):

Google has refreshed the look of the icons (and other things).
The new default icon is 
[this one here](http://mt.googleapis.com/vt/icon/name=icons/spotlight/spotlight-poi.png).

Other icons with this look can be found/made [here](https://mts.googleapis.com/vt/icon/name=icons/spotlight/spotlight-waypoint-a.png&text=Z&psize=11&font=fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf&color=ff333333&ax=44&ay=48&scale=1).

^(By editing that URL, you can get the icons with letters inside, other colors, different sizes, &c.)

Comment: See this post for array of icons that can be used: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17746740/google-map-icons-with-visualrefresh

Answer (score 1):

The list is [here & hosted by google](https://sites.google.com/site/gmapsdevelopment/). This lists them all(or most of them) out with the url to point to them.

Remember: They work with `HTTPS://` and `HTTP://`

Using it:

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng, // this var would be set before calling this
    map: map, // this var would be set on initiating the api
    title: 'The location of the Million Dollars!',
    icon: 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png' // This is where you put the icon url
});
```