# What are the filenames of new colored Google maps markers?

Tags: image, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, icons

Is there a handy guide similar to [this one](http://mabp.kiev.ua/2010/01/12/google-map-markers/) for the newer Google markers that reside in the directory http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/ ?

So far I have been able to find these:

- Red marker with black dot

  http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/marker.png
- Green marker with letter A (can be any letter)

  http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/marker_greenA.png
- Marker shadow

  http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/shadow50.png
- Green downward arrow

  http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/arrow.png
- Arrow shadow

  http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/arrowshadow.png

For my particular application I'd like to find the green marker with a black dot, but so far no luck. Anyone else find other icons from this directory?

Comment: One point about all these - they are available over https which the old ones (from labs.google.com etc) aren't

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That's what I got so far:

- [`drag_cross_67_16.png`](http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/drag_cross_67_16.png)
- [`measle.png`](http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/measle.png)
- [`measle_blue.png`](http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/measle_blue.png)
- [`dd-via.png`](http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/dd-via.png)
- [`dd-via-transparent.png`](http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/dd-via-transparent.png)
- [`arrowshadow.png`](http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/arrowshadow.png)
- [`arrow.png`](http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/arrow.png)
- [`arrowtransparent.png`](http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/arrowtransparent.png)
- [`shadow50.png`](http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/shadow50.png)
- [`marker_sprite.png`](http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/marker_sprite.png)
- [**`icon_green.png`**](http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/icon_green.png)    **<----------------------------- what you are looking for**
- [`marker.png`](http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/marker.png)
- [`boost-marker-mapview.png`](http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/boost-marker-mapview.png)
- *`circle[A-J].png`*
- [`red_circle_markers_A_J2.png`](http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/red_circle_markers_A_J2.png)
- [`red_transparent_circle_icons_A_J.png`](http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/red_transparent_circle_icons_A_J.png)
- *`marker[A-J].png`*
- [`red_transparent_icons_A_J.png`](http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/red_transparent_icons_A_J.png)
- [`red_icons_A_J.png`](http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/red_icons_A_J.png)
- [`red_markers_A_J2.png`](http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/red_markers_A_J2.png)
- [`red_grow_markers_A_J2.png`](http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/red_grow_markers_A_J2.png)
- *`marker_green[A-Z].png`*
- *`icon_green[A-Z].png`*
- [`markerTransparent.png`](http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/markerTransparent.png)

Overview: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/LS7Wj/show/

Answer (score 8):

[Concept221](https://github.com/Concept211/) has taken care of rolling the v3 map icons for 9 pre-rendered colors. They also wrote a program for creating custom ones.

https://github.com/Concept211/Google-Maps-Markers

> colors: red, green, purple, orange, white, blue, yellow, black
>
> characters: A-Z, 1-100, !, @, $, +, -, =, (%23 = #), (%25 = %), (%26 = &), (blank = •)
>
> [image: New Red Dot]
>   [image: New Green A]
>   [image: New Purple 1]
>   [image: New Orange @]
>   [image: New White 99]
>   [image: New Blue #]
>   [image: New Yellow +]
>   [image: New Black Z]

*The border might be a hair thinner than the early v3 icons, but they seem to match well with the current ones (2017). Otherwise they look the same to me.*

Answer (score 4):

Could this URL be what you are looking for?

https://mt.google.com/vt/icon?psize=20&font=fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf&color=ff330000&name=icons/spotlight/spotlight-waypoint-a.png&ax=44&ay=48&scale=1&text=%E2%80%A2

I found that the new google maps version uses some kind of service to build icons dynamically (not documented afaik). You can change the values in the URL to change the size/color of the icon and size/color/font/position of the text. In the example above, %E2%80%A2 corresponds to • (`&bull;`)

Comment: Where do you find the values you can use for the icon name in this link?  (I.e., what other values besides icons/spotlight/spotlight-waypoint-a)

Comment: Yeah, adjusting the color value in that URL doesn't change the marker color. It changes the icon color. (It also seems to be a weird format: ARGB instead of RGBA)

Answer (score 2):

https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?dsrcid=308519#map:id=3 here is all the icons you can use on google maps.

Comment: These are the old icons.

Comment: well the answer is posted a year ago :)

Comment: Ha, yes, but those were already a version or two old then. Off the top of my head, I place that style as pre-2014. Still, that is a good source for a wide variety of icons.

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: Yes, that is posted 6 years ago. Google and google maps changed a lot since then