# Changing Color of New Google Markers (Google JS API v3)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Does anyone know if there is a way to change the color of the **new** Google Maps markers in the Javascript v3 API without creating custom images? I only want to use official markers.

This is the old way to use custom colors but the images are old: http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|FE7569

[image]

I'm trying to use the new ones which look much cleaner but I can only use the default color and I need to use multiple colors:

[image]

These are still using old too:
http://maps.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/red-dot.png

I also don't see anything new on their icons page: https://sites.google.com/site/gmapsdevelopment/

--

**Edit**: So, far all I've found of the new colors is the following which are using png files to change the color of the marker itself not the text on the icon:

- Default red: https://mt.google.com/vt/icon?psize=20&font=fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf&color=ff330000&name=icons/spotlight/spotlight-waypoint-b.png&ax=44&ay=48&scale=1&text=%E2%80%A2
- Green: https://mt.google.com/vt/icon?psize=20&font=fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf&color=ff330000&name=icons/spotlight/spotlight-waypoint-a.png&ax=44&ay=48&scale=1&text=%E2%80%A2

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the filenames of new colored Google maps markers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19142242/what-are-the-filenames-of-new-colored-google-maps-markers)

Comment: That post only has the default red and green one but you can modify the text on the marker. I need more than 2 colors. It doesn't look like more colors are available yet. Also, they are using png files to modify the icon; Its not dynamic like there old method posted at the top of my post.

Comment: @Anna - Have you made any progress in figuring this out?

Comment: Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44332827/3003133), with: https://github.com/Concept211/Google-Maps-Markers

Answer (score -2):

Here are some that i found

http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png

red-dot.png

/orange-dot.png

/yellow-dot.png

/green-dot.png

/pink-dot.png

EDIT:

I doubt what you consider as "new markers" is just another type of icons (notice in the url &name=icons/spotlight). Apart from what you found I could only find one more => spotlight-waypoint-blue.png
https://mt.google.com/vt/icon?psize=20&font=fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf&color=ff330000&name=icons/spotlight/spotlight-waypoint-blue.png&ax=44&ay=48&scale=1&text=%E2%80%A2

Also seems that Google Chart Tools Infographics have been deprecated check here (developers.google.com/chart/infographics/). Since I couldn't find any documentation from google as to what is the future for infographics, if I were you I will stick to the old ones. And if you're paranoid like me and worry that these icons might disappear later, you may want to copy to your own server to be sure.

Comment: These are the old ones. I'm looking for the new ones and all I've found is the default red one and the green one.