# Google Maps Default Icons

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, icons, google-maps-markers

I am trying to get the current default Google Maps Icons.

I am making a program with the Google Maps API and have set my DirectionsRenderer to suppress markers so I can make markers to set the specific icon.

This is my current result:

[image]

This is what I had before suppressing the default markers:

[image]

Later in my program I will be adding waypoints so I would like to set markers like the ones above with the letter A, B, C, etc. with a different color, (like marker "A", which is green).

I have visited several sites such as:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-symbol-predefined

https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?dsrcid=308519#map:id=3

[google maps v3 standard icon/shadow names (equiv. of G_DEFAULT_ICON in v2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248077/google-maps-v3-standard-icon-shadow-names-equiv-of-g-default-icon-in-v2)

The markers these websites tell you to use, do not look the same as the current markers. I am wondering if there is a way to call the current "green marker a" just like in the fusion tables:

[image]

If so, how? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you'll find here what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19142242/what-are-the-filenames-of-new-colored-google-maps-markers/19147695#19147695

Comment: @Dr.Molle I believe it's a start, it doesn't look exactly like the new icons though

Comment: The best one I found was here on this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17746740/google-map-icons-with-visualrefresh

Comment: Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44332827/3003133), with: https://github.com/Concept211/Google-Maps-Markers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you take a look at the network-tab of the developer-tools you'll see that the URL for the green marker is:

```
https://mts.googleapis.com/vt/icon/name=icons/spotlight/spotlight-waypoint-a.png&text=A&psize=16&font=fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf&color=ff333333&ax=44&ay=48&scale=1
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

The letter may be defined via the `text`-parameter

(Note: there is also a `color`-parameter, this parameter is used for the text-color and not for the background of the marker)

Comment: Thank you very much, I was unaware of this!

Comment: The Developer-Tools "Networking Tab" is a very efficent method, I will be using it more often

Comment: Quick question, can I change the color of the icon? Something like yellow or blue? I have changed `spotlight-waypoint-a` to `spotlight-waypoint-b` and it gives me red, but there is nothing after that

Comment: I can't tell you(maybe it's notpossible)

Comment: I have found this https://mts.googleapis.com/vt/icon/name=icons/spotlight/spotlight-waypoint-blue.png&psize=16&font=fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf&color=ff333333&ax=44&ay=48&scale=1 but I cannot get rid of the circle in the middle

Comment: the following claims to provide 26 (A-Z) pins in 10 colors. http://www.benjaminkeen.com/google-maps-coloured-markers/comment-page-3/

Answer (score 4):

This post was old. I hope my answer that will help people to do that.

```
            for (var i = 0; i < listMarkers.length; i++) { //loop markers
                if (listMarkers[i].icon) { // if icon is set
                    listMarkers[i].setIcon(); //set default 
                    break;
                }
            }
```