# Google Maps API v3 - Add a placemark control

Tags: google-maps

I've been researching on this for some days but can't find a proper answer neither here nor in the API's doc.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3428472/download.png

I'm looking for a way to add that control to a gmaps implementation. I guess I could go for designing a custom control but since this one already exists, there must be a way of adding it as is.

That is the blue drop a pin control available in the edit mode of the places API.
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: *"since this one already exists, there must be a way..."* ... I'm not sure if this logic works with google... The fact they have it at maps.google.com doesn't mean they provide it in the API. BTW, the icons provided there are also not given as ["starndard set icons"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8248077/)....

Comment: Let's just say I'm hoping I won't have to make a custom control :)

Comment: I'm not sure if you can just "steal" it from the maps.google.com, maybe look at the licence. And maybe the code is obfuscated... you have to check it.

Comment: will take a further look. I wouldn't want to steal it anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image looks like an implementation of the drawing-library.
There is no need to steal something, it's a part of the public API.

You'll find the docs here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays?hl=en#drawing_tools

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been looking a long time for this one.