# change google map marker color to a color of my choice

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there anyway to change from the default red marker color to a hexidecimal color of my choice? I've been looking all over stack overflow and I haven't seem to find an answer. This is what I have so far.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            label: '23',
            map: map
        });
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One option would be to define an SVG symbol for the marker icon.  SVG icon colors can be set in their constructor.

```
function pinSymbol(color) {
    return {
        path: 'M 0,0 C -2,-20 -10,-22 -10,-30 A 10,10 0 1,1 10,-30 C 10,-22 2,-20 0,0 z',
        fillColor: color,
        fillOpacity: 1,
        strokeColor: '#000',
        strokeWeight: 2,
        scale: 1
    };
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(47.5, -122.0),
  icon: pinSymbol('green')
});
```

[image]

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s3db77ff/3/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(47.605, -122.2);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    myOptions);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: latlng,
    icon: pinSymbol('red')
  });

  var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(47.5, -122.0),
    icon: pinSymbol('#7CFC00')
  });
  var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(47.6, -122.3),
    icon: pinSymbol('orange')
  });
  var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(47.7, -122.1),
    icon: pinSymbol('yellow')
  });
}

function pinSymbol(color) {
  return {
    path: 'M 0,0 C -2,-20 -10,-22 -10,-30 A 10,10 0 1,1 10,-30 C 10,-22 2,-20 0,0 z',
    fillColor: color,
    fillOpacity: 1,
    strokeColor: '#000',
    strokeWeight: 2,
    scale: 1
  };
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:750px; height:450px; border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the marker  don't have a color property/attribute .. the markers use icon so you can change color changing icon

this is from google-maps dev

> ```
> var image = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png';
> var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
>    position: {lat: -33.890, lng: 151.274},
>    map: map,
>    icon: image
>  });
> ```

Comment: is there a google map icon website that I can look through? I don't need a fancy icon, just the same icon google has but a different background color

Comment: take a look at this  SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248077/google-maps-v3-standard-icon-shadow-names-equiv-of-g-default-icon-in-v2   or you can search on site like this http://miftyisbored.com/a-complete-list-of-standard-google-maps-marker-icons/

Comment: the thing is that the icon colors they have are very generic like 'blue', 'green' etc. I have a specific hexadecimal color code that I want the marker to have

Comment: @beewuu   you can build an icon like you  prefer ..is a normal png. save it in an accessible  site area and then load with the sample provided and use  ..