# How to change only the color of pin

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I have google Marker.
In default [image]

I can make the pin with letters in it

Then I want to change the color of this pin .

So, I try with this icon
[image]
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=|0099cc|

Letters are shift and the size is slightly changed....

I use `color : "blue"` instead but in vain.

How can I change only the color of pin???

```
    var marker =new google.maps.Marker({
        position:latlng,
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
        icon: "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=|0099cc|",
        //icon: "https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png",
        //icon: "https://mts.googleapis.com/vt/icon/name=icons/spotlight/spotlight-poi.png&scale=1",
        map:this.map,
        color: "blue" // it dosen't work
        label: String(label),
        title:"google map"
    });
```

Comment: Related question: [Google maps change marker color based on xml value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57583604/google-maps-change-marker-color-based-on-xml-value)

Comment: 1) `path` is not a [MarkerOption](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker?hl=en#MarkerOptions) and neither is `color` 2) The icons you are using are from the [Image Charts API](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/dynamic_icons) that was deprecated in 2012 and turned off in 2019. I am even surprised that you still can get an icon... 3) There are many way to create a custom Marker. You should refer to the docs or the many tutorials around

Comment: Thank you my API is Google Maps API version: 3.40.6.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved.

I use

`icon: http://www.googlemapsmarkers.com/v1/S/ff5c5a/`;

I can change the color and text like

`icon: http://www.googlemapsmarkers.com/v1/S/ff5c5a/`; show color ff5c5a and label `S`

`icon: http://www.googlemapsmarkers.com/v1/A/bb335a/`; show color bb335a and label `A`

Answer (score -1):

use this:

```
icon: { url: "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=|0099cc|",
        size: new google.maps.Size(20, 32) // resize as you like
      }
```

Comment: THank you very much but it has dot in it. So I can't put the text...

Comment: So if the problem is the size of the pin you can resize it as you want. see my code edited

Comment: Thank you, but size doesn't change for now.